# Iterating over map using 'for' loops in dart

Tags: dart

I have a map type variable. I want Iterating over map using 'for' loops.I tried with the following code but got an error:

```
var m = {"key1":12 , "key2":24};
for(final key,value in m){
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
m.forEach((key,value) {
    //some code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate hash map elements using map entries:

```
void main() {
  var m = {'key1': 12, 'key2': 24};
  for (final entry in m.entries) {
    print(entry.key);
    print(entry.value);
  }
}
```